# Panel in JLayeredPane shows buttons behind of it

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I have some buttons, panels over a JLayeredPane.

When I click a button, a panel shows up by setvisible(true). But if there is a button behind panel and I hover on button button comes over panel.

I am using JLayeredPane to move panel front.

This is what happens when I click button to show panel.

```
   private void jbOffCenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    if(!offsetedilmis)
    {
    jPOffsetSor.setVisible(true);
    KHLayered.moveToFront(jPOffsetSor);
    offsetedilmis = true;
    jbOffCen.setText("<html><center>RESET<br>CENTRE");
    }
    else if(offsetedilmis)
    {
    jbOffCen.setText("<html><center>OFFSET<br>CENTRE");
    offsetedilmis = true;
    }
}
```

Btw, I am using netbeans' designer.

Auto generated code to add panel to JLayeredPanel:

```
KHLayered.add(jPOffsetSor, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 250, 450, 150));
```

Main screen without any click.
[image: First]

Click on OFFSET CENTRE button and panel shows up.
[image: Second]

If I hover on buttons behind panel, they comes front. But I have already move panel to front. Should I set some property on/off for buttons or panel?
[image: third]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

Setting panels layer to POPUP_LAYER or MODAL_LAYER solves problem.

```
 KHLayered.setLayer(jPManOverSil, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Jpanel to show a message you can try to use a [dialogue window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

For this example you can use (try this code, but it can contain errors):

```
Object[] options = {"<html><center>RESET<br>CENTRE",
                "<html><center>OFFSET<br>CENTRE"};
int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
"Left click...", // the title of the window
"Pop-up window", // the meassage in the window
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null, 
options,  //the titles of buttons
options[0]);
```

You have a lot of other options. you can explore it in the api or in the website I gave previously.

It is much simplier, because you don't need to have actionperformed methods!

Good Work!

Comment: Actually I know these windows (dialog, frame etc. ) But according to documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html it should work. But if I can't figure it out, I am going to use them. Thanks for advice.